# Figuring out the meaning and syntax of the English translation of Charmides

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, semantics, archaicisms

I was reading *The Dialogues of Socrates* translated into English and one particular sentence in *Charmides* sprung out as odd. I can't tell what it is trying to say, but I also can't figure out if it is grammatically correct or not.

> Very good, I said; and did you not admit, just now, that temperance is noble?
>
> Yes, certainly, he said.
>
> And the temperate are also good?
>
> Yes.
>
> **And can that be good which does not make men good?**
>
> Certainly not.

I'm guessing that this is correct English but it simply fell out of usage in modern times (e.g. saying "[VERB] + not" instead of "Do + not + [VERB]" for negation). Having said all that, I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: And can something be said to be good if it doesn’t make men good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an [extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition) in there.

A more normal order would be

> Can that which does not make men good be good?

but (especially in writing) this is ***less*** comprehensible, because of the difficulty of finding the end of the relative clause *which does not make men good*.

Also *that which ...* is somewhat literary: a more ordinary form would be *something which*.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I understand what it means now, the reordered version makes a lot more sense to me. I would think for comprehensibility, I would put a comma in it: *... make men good, be good?* I'm still about confused about the syntax. From a syntactic-analysis POV, how does this work? Let's say, for example, I am writing a story; when would it be appropriate to do this and how?

Comment: Did you read the WP article? It can be appropriate in any writing (and even sometimes in speech) when a short constituent (typically an object) would be separated from whatever governs it by a long constituent, typically a NP with an embedded clause.

Comment: I did read the the Wikipedia article, but I wasn't entirely sure what I was reading. I don't have much knowledge about "constituents" and such.

Comment: @thepufferfish: Informally, a constituent is a word or sequence of words in a sentence that hangs together as a unit. In the previous sentence, "a word", "sequence of words", "a word or sequence of words", and "that hangs together as a unit" are all constituents, but "sequence of", "word or sequence", and "words that hangs" are not. It is sometimes not clear-cut whether a sequence of words is a constituent or not (and it may depend on the way the sentence is analysed) but generally it's obvious.