# What were/are the rules regarding relative pronouns from c. 1800?

Tags: history, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, archaicisms

I've been reading some rather old literature, often ranging from the 18th Century through to the late 19th Century, and I'm trying to increase my comprehension of the material, at least to the extent that, if I wanted to, I could reliably write in a similar manner and be grammatically correct by the grammar rules of that time. I find that one of the more confusing aspects of this to be the use of relative pronouns, sometimes using *which* in situations that in wouldn't be during the mid-20th Century through to the  present.

Basically, what I am asking is, in a historical context (i.e. not necessarily standard to our English today), what were the distinctions in use and meaning between *that*, *which*, *who/whom*, etc.?

Comment: I'm just adding this in a comment as it isn't relevant to the actual question, but I'm looking for resources (e.g. books, websites, etc.) on learning these kind of grammatical archaicisms. I've already run into trouble with [extraposition in a translation of Plato](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/543609/figuring-out-the-meaning-and-syntax-of-the-english-translation-of-charmides), and I would much prefer it if there was simply an outlined guide to this kind of English.

Comment: Also, just to note; the reason why I wrote the titular question with *were/are* is because I'm not entirely sure about how phased-out each of those rules are, so I figured that it would be an easy way of settling any complications there.

Comment: This might be better served as a request for resources (18th and 19th century grammars, for example) on the ELU meta site. Here, on ELU main, the question, or rather the answers, seem to be a bit broad.

Comment: @JEL I've [posted this question onto the meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14810/are-there-any-resources-for-18th-and-19th-century-english-grammar) which features a link back to this page.

Comment: Perhaps you could cite some examples?